# I am reading from a file using a Fraction Lib but im getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java, android

```
 public static void readFile() {

    int num, den;
    int row = 0, column = 0;

    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\camil\\IdeaProjects\\LAB1-434\\src\\MatrixA.txt");
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        fRow = sc.nextInt(); to get the size of my matrix
        fCol = sc.nextInt();
        while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            for (row = 0; row < fRow; row++) {
                for (column = 0; column < fCol; column++) {

                    num = sc.nextInt();
                    den = sc.nextInt();

                    Fraction[][] fArray = new Fraction[row][column];
                    Fraction f = new Fraction(num, den);

                    System.out.print("|" + f + "| "); ** just to test it and it is reading the values correctly** 

                    fArray[row][column] = f;    **im getting the error at these two lines**
                    System.out.print(fArray[row][column]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        **...**
```

My text file looks like this (the first two lines are for the size and the rest are 1 for numerator the other for the denominator)

> 3 3
>   1 8 1 7 1 2
>   1 8 1 3 1 13
>   1 3 1 8 1 16

While testing my code without trying to generate a new array it was working perfectly fine but When I add the last two lines, I am getting the array out of bounds error

Comment: Please provide your logcat

Comment: If you notice In your code and as far as I can figure out; you will see that the value of the matrix(i.e. rows and columns) is 3 3 but in the file you are providing **18 elements**. Sounds a bit naive. Isn't it?And that I think is the place where `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` Exception occurs

Comment: Debug and look at the creation of `fArray` (which happens every iteration so the prior iteration is thrown away).

Answer (score 0):

The following piece of code creates an empty array in the beginning (as both row=0 and column=0).

```
Fraction[][] fArray = new Fraction[row][column];
```

Therefore, the subsequent initialisation gives java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

```
fArray[row][column] = f;
```

Looks like this is an oversight while coding; probably it should be coded as:

```
Fraction[][] fArray = new Fraction[fRow][fCol];
```

Answer (score 0):

Saurabh is right. You should also create the array outside of the for loops. And as far as I can see, the while loop is not necessary because the for loops process everything and the while loop is only ran through once.

```
Fraction[][] fArray = new Fraction[fRow][fCol];
for(int row = 0;row<fRow;row++){
    for(int column=0;column<fCol;column++){
        //Scanner.nextInt() and create instances of Fraction and fill in array here
        //do other stuff
    }
}
```